# how do i make my navigation bar more responsive without added more media queries?

Tags: html, css

I made a Navigation bar in the header and have added media queries for mobile devices and table but any thing in middle of this makes the page layout look bad so do i need to add more media queries for all measurements or is there an other way of making page more responsive.

I tried doing it with media queries but was wondering if their is another way around.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 2):

You can use libraries like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/) and its easy to learn and use,
or you can just use flexbox or grids in CSS.

[Learn more about Flexbox on MDN, using this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

[Learn more about the CSS Grid Layout system on MDN, using this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Answer (score 0):

you can use your same media queries but make sure that your sizes are in

> em
> or
> %

in this case everything will go smaller and bigger according to the user's device width.

that's in case you don't want to use a css library which is also recommended.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets keep all simple, is not required to use libraries to build a responsive views

[image]

You need to implement *mobile first*, implement mobile then you can adjust only required elements to other break points (tablet, desktop, ...)
Here you can use **break points**, **flex**, **grid** and positions

Manage all spaces (margins, paddings) with parent container to make less changes, here you can take advantage of **flex** and **grid** to centered and spaces between elements the trick is property **gap**, in this days is not required to use tables to adjust elements

If you are building components dont forget, all components should be reusable, configurable and mantenible

Here is some interesting content:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries